# Monitoring Elastic cloud cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I have two elastic cloud cluster. Yesterday I have an issue in one of them because the cluster had no space left, but I noticed it because I logged in elastic cloud console. I need some tool to have alerts when the cluster are with problems. I'm looking for internet about it but I don't find any tool to monitor it.
Is there any tool to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Elastic Cloud, there was various alerts that you can set up in order to be notified of deployment health issues, such as disk usage, CPU usage, JVM memory usage and many more.

All the steps are described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-cluster-health-notifications.html), but basically, you need:

1. To [enable logging and monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-enable-logging-and-monitoring.html)

[image: logging and monitoring]

2. Configure an [email connector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.10/email-action-type.html#elasticcloud) in Kibana
3. In Kibana, go to Stack Monitoring
4. Enable Set up mode

[image: set up mode]

5. Click on the Node rules and select "Resource utilization > Disk Usage"

[image: resource utilization]

6. Edit the rule to match your requirements and send an email when thresholds are crossed

[image: edit rule]

Comment: Thanks, but I need to monitor outside the cluster, because, if the cluster gets down, I supouse it can't sent the alert, right?

Comment: In the first step, the best practice is to select another deployment in the "Shipping data to" section to receive the logs and metrics which is different than your production cluster, that way if your cluster gets down, you can still get alerted... and if it's down you have more serious issues to solve than just disk space ;-)

Comment: While the (external) monitoring cluster is definitely recommended, it shouldn't be necessary for the disk space. For that [operational emails](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-operational-emails.html) should be kicking in.

Answer (score 0):

Operational emails (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-operational-emails.html) should be sent automatically and one of the triggers is if any node reaches 90% of the available disk. You didn't receive that one?

PS: Running out of disk is a stupid problem but you can avoid that with autoscaling, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-autoscaling.html.

Comment: Thanks, I 've already known how autoscaling works. I have set up the operational emails and works as expected. Thanks